# I tried to write a Wordpress plugin, but I failed

Tags: php, wordpress

I write a simple wordpress plugins ..

it is for friend blogs , using wordpres 3

but I don't know where is the problem ..

this is the code ..

```
<?
/*
Plugin Name:  RandFriendB
Plugin URI: http://www.abosami.com
Description: Show your frineds blogs ..
Version: 1.0
Author: abosami
Author URI: http://www.abosami.com
*/
load_plugin_textdomain('randfriendb', "/wp-content/plugins/randfriendb/");
function randfriendb_admin()
    {
function table_exists ($table, $db=DB_NAME) {
        $tables = mysql_list_tables ($db);
        while (list ($temp) = mysql_fetch_array ($tables)) {
                if ($temp == $table) {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
        return FALSE;
}
if (!table_exists("wp_randfb"))
        {
        $create = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `wp_randfb` (
                    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    `blog_title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    `blog_url` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    `blog_desc` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
                    )
                    ");
            if ($create)
                {
                 echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("The table is created","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />'.__("please wait ...","randfriendb");
                echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=admin.php?page=randfriendb/randfriendb.php&action=add">';
                }else{
                         echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("error","randfriendb").'</h2></div>';
                         echo mysql_error();
                }
        }else{
        if (!isset($_GET['action']) || $_GET['action'] == "add")
            {
                echo '<form method="POST" action="admin.php?page=randfriendb/randfriendb.php&action=insert">
                <div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("Add New blog:","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />
                <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                <th>'.__("Blog Title:","randfriendb"). '<span class="description"></span></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="blog_title" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>'.__("Blog URL:","randfriendb").'<span class="description"></span></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="blog_url" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>'.__("Description:","randfriendb").' <span class="description"></span></th>
                <td><textarea name="blog_desc" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                </table>
                <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="'.__("Add","randfriendb").'" name="submit" />
                </p>

                </div>
                </form>
                ';

            }elseif($_GET['action'] == "edit")
                    {
                    global $wpdb;
                    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_randfb`",ARRAY_A);

                    if ($blogs)
                        {
                        echo '
                        <br/><table class="widefat post fixed" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-title" style="">'.__("Blog Title:","randfriendb").'</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-author" style="">'.__("Blog URL:","randfriendb").'</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-categories" style="">'.__("Description:","randfriendb").'</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-tags" style="">'.__("Delete","randfriendb").'</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        ';
                        foreach($blogs as $blog){
                        echo '<tr id="post-1" class="alternate author-self status-publish iedit" valign="top">
                        <td>'.$blog['blog_title'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$blog['blog_url'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$blog['blog_desc'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td><a href="admin.php?page=randfriendb/randfriendb.php&action=del&id='.$blog[id].'">'.__("Delete","randfriendb").'</a></td></tr>';
                        }
                        echo '  <tfoot>
                                <tr >
                                    <th colspan="4"></th>
                                </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                </table>';
                        }else{
                        echo '<h3>'.__("No found new blogs","randfriendb").'</h3>';
                        }


                    }elseif($_GET['action'] == "del")
                        {
                        global $wpdb;
                        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
                        $del = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `wp_randfb` WHERE id='" . $id . "'");
                        if ($del)
                            {
                            echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("The blog is deleted","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />'.__("Please waith ...","randfriendb");
                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=admin.php?page=randfriendb/randfriendb.php&action=edit">';
                            }else{
                            echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("Error","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />';
                            }

                        }elseif($_GET['action'] == "insert")
                            {
                            if(empty($_POST['blog_title']) || empty($_POST['blog_url']) || empty($_POST['blog_desc']))
                                {
                                echo '<h2>'.__("Please write the information","randfriendb").'</h2>';
                                }else{
                                global $wpdb;
                                $insert = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wp_randfb` VALUES(NULL,'" . $_POST['blog_title'] . "','" . $_POST['blog_url'] . "','" . $_POST['blog_desc'] . "')");
                                if ($insert)
                                    {
                                    echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("The blog is added","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />'.__("Please wait ...","randfriendb");
                                    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=admin.php?page=randfriendb/randfriendb.php&action=edit">';
                                    }else{
                                    echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.__("Error","randfriendb").'</h2></div><br />';                                    
                                    }

                                }

                            }



            }



    }   
function randfriendb_add_admin() {
add_menu_page(__("Friend Blogs","randfriendb"),__("Friend Blogs","randfriendb"), 8, __FILE__, "randfriendb_admin");
add_submenu_page(__FILE__, __("New Blog","randfriendb"), __("New Blog","randfriendb"), 8,__FILE__ , "randfriendb_admin");
add_submenu_page(__FILE__, __("Control","randfriendb"), __("Control","randfriendb"), 8, __FILE__ ."&action=edit", "randfriendb_admin");
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'randfriendb_add_admin');  
 function randfriendb_main($args)
    {
    extract($args);
    global $wpdb;
    $get_blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_randfb` order by rand() limit 0,1",ARRAY_A);
    foreach($get_blogs as $get_blog){
    echo $before_widget;
    echo $before_title;
     _e("Friend Blogs","randfriendb");
     echo $after_title;
    echo '<a href="'.$get_blog['blog_url'].'">'.$get_blog['blog_title'].'</a><p>'.$get_blog['blog_desc'].'</p>'.$after_widget;
    }
    }


    register_sidebar_widget(__("Friend Blogs","randfriendb"),'randfriendb_main');





?>
```

Comment: What did you want the plugin to do? What does it actually do? What steps did you take to try and fix the problem?

Comment: I want from the plugins to show a random frined blogs , there are a form to add the blog with title , url , description , also there is a menu blogs to remove , edit , ...
also there is  a widget to show random blog ..

Comment: the problem when I refresh the admin page ..
there is error , I don't know ..

Comment: I will take a print screen for the page .. please wait me ^_^

Comment: this is when I refrech the page after activite the plugin ..
in a header page : http://filaty.com/i/1008/12242/error.JPG ..

Comment: "I tried to write a Wordpress plugin, but I failed." I want to give +1 just for the title.  But I won't ;-)  Your link to the error message is dead, and so there's effectively no historical benefit in keeping this post here IMHO.  I've flagged for deletion as such.  If you've since found a solution, please update the OP with clear description of what was actually wrong, and then answer your own question detailing how you fixed the issue (and accept it as the solution).

Comment: Before you go even further with this kind of "plugin development", I suggest to start clean, basing on, for example https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate. You can generate a ready plugin skeleton (basing on this boilerplate) here: http://codegen.kickapz.com/. From there, you can take a look at http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/08/ten-things-every-wordpress-plugin-developer-should-know/ and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/715/27835. Once you have a good base, you can start thinking of writing some actual code that will accomplish certain tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code and the screenshot I noticed you're using short tags `<?`. Your server may not have this enabled, hence why your code is spilling out all over your page. Try `<?php` instead.

Comment: I change it but the problem still after using <?php ..

thankyou very much for helping me ..

I wait u

Comment: +1 Good pickup all those years back. "I tried to write a Wordpress plugin, but I failed." Gold.  Based on that title, I came here expecting a novel or autobiography. I failed. :-)